# oauth2 callback displays referenced stylesheet css file literally

Tags: html, css, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have a spring boot application that uses a GitHub oauth2 app for authentication.

When the successful authentication returns then one of the stylesheet files will be displayed. Literally. It is a random choice as to which one it is. The browser is firefox. The url will be http://machine:8090/css/demo.css. Resending http://machine:8090 will then display the screen properly.

Commenting out the css lines in the html will display the expected result after a return from github. But obviously I lose any formatting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bikes Application</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.8/dist/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!--       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css"/>  
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  -->

   </head>
   <body>


      <div id="app-3" class="container">
         <template v-if="!authd">
            <a href = "/login">Click here to Github Login</a>
         </template>
         <template v-else>
             Logged in as: <span id="user">{{ user }}</span>
             <div>
                 <button v-on:click="logout" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
             </div>

             <p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>

             <p>Listing Owners and their bikes with Thymeleaf <a href="/nutsthymeleaf">here</a></p>

             <p>Listing Owners and their bikes with vue in a thymeleaf template <a href="/nutsvuejs">here</a></p>
         </template>
      </div>


      <script type="application/javascript" src="authorisation.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Update from comments.

I don't think it is connected to grant types because if, before authentication, I go to machine:8090/greeting for instance then I am redirected to GitHub, authenticate and then passed to greeting (which does contain a subset of the css files listed in index.html). And that works; the contents of css is not listed.

The oauth app in GitHub has a redirect url of machine:8090/login. I have tried machine:8090/ and get the same result - after authentication, I see a css file listed.

Here is WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
//@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@PropertySources(
        {
            @PropertySource("classpath:application-github.properties")
        }
)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
//        .csrf()
//        .disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/unpkg.com/**", "/cdn.jsdelivr.net","/error**","/*.js","/*.css")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

I have expanded index.html. Are there other files that would be helpful?

and here is the javascript

```
vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app-3',
    data: function() {
      return {
        user: null,
        baseurl: "http://mint191:9080/",
        authd: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      logout: function () {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'logout',
          baseURL: this.baseurl
        })
          .then(response => {
              console.log(`post logout: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
              this.user = null
              this.authd = !this.authd
              console.log(`logout: authorised is ${this.authd}`)
              console.log(`logout: user is ${this.user}`)       
            })    
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log("logout has gone wrong" + error)
            })   
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'user',
        baseURL: this.baseurl
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(`get user: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)
          this.user = response.data.userAuthentication.details.login
          this.authd = !this.authd
          console.log(`authorised is ${this.authd}`)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("nothing in user" + error)
        })
    }
  })
```

Comment: Which grant_type / flow do you use ? Have you specified redirect_url (is supported by the flow) ? Have app granted permission ? Can you add more details / code to the question ?

Comment: Within the GitHub oauth app, the callback url is machine:8090/login.
"app granted permission" - in the GitHub app? My Spring Boot app? I am following the spring guide for external oauth.

Comment: I suggest you to read about [grant_types](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/). Anyway you must update your question and add more code to better understand whats going on. Add the code relative to the auth, which urls do you call, etc.